# Determining orbit ground track

Tags: orbit

I have the orbital elements of a satellite orbit around earth. It is an inclined elliptical orbit. I have plotted the orbit in 3D and have all the position vectors of the orbit.

I am now trying to plot a ground track of the orbit on MATLAB and I am unsure where to start. I am looking for guidance on the steps required to achieve this

Comment: If you have the orbit in 3D and just need an approximation, you could draw a vector from the position of the satellite to the center of the Earth and figure out where it hits the surface of the Earth. For more accuracy, consider using the CSPICE libraries: http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/tutorials.html